# canvas: not all objects in an array of bouncing ball objects are showing up

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, html5-canvas, single-page-application, vue-directives

I've created a spa/rest/crud application using laravel 5.5, vuejs and vue-router. Now the idea came to mind to use a component for the landing page  and spice that up a bit with canvas. (Originally p5.js, but i gave up on that for now.) So far so good. I got the Vue components working through the Vue-Router and for the front-page i made a component with a custom directive that feeds the canvas element in the template its data (in the form of a ball object)

Now since i had to switch to Canvas which i'm not really familiar with i ran into a problem. As a test i put 4 balls into an array. But only 1 is showing. Now when i disable the clearRect function. They do show up in a messy way. I had to use  beginPath() apparently to keep the balls from  'trailing'. But when i do that just one shows up. Maybe it's a simple thing i'm overlooking. I'll post the part i think is causing the problem below:

```
<script>            
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {

        }
    },
    directives: {
      bindCanvas: {

        inserted: function (el) {
            var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
            var Ball = function(x,y,r){
                this.position = {};
                this.position.x = x;
                this.position.y = y;
                //i could not use vectors so i came up with this solution
                this.velocity = {x:0,y:0};
                this.acceleration = {x:0,y:0};                  
                this.radius = r;
            };
            Ball.prototype.addForce = function(x,y){

                this.acceleration.x += x/1000;
                this.acceleration.y += y/1000;

            };
            Ball.prototype.move = function(){                   

                this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
                this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
                this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x;
                this.velocity.y += this.acceleration.y;

                //reset acceleration to 0
                this.acceleration.x *= 0;
                this.acceleration.y *= 0;
            };
            Ball.prototype.display = function(){
                //here is the problem somewhere i think.
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
                ctx.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.radius,0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fill();
            };

            Ball.prototype.checkBorders = function(){
                if(this.position.x > ctx.canvas.width-(this.radius/2)){
                    this.velocity.x = this.velocity.x *-1;
                } else if (this.position.x < 0){
                    this.velocity.x *= -1;
                }
                if (this.position.y > ctx.canvas.height-(this.radius/2)){
                    this.velocity.y *= -1;
                } else if(this.position.y < 0){
                    this.velocity.y *= -1;
                }
            };

            Ball.prototype.checkMaxSpeed = function(){
                if(this.velocity.x > 0.5){
                    this.velocity.x = 0.5;
                }
                if(this.velocity.x < -0.5){
                    this.velocity.x = -0.5;
                }
                if(this.velocity.y > 0.5){
                    this.velocity.y = 0.5;
                }
                if(this.velocity.y < -0.5){
                    this.velocity.y = -0.5;
                }
            };

            var arrayOfBalls = [];

            for(var i=0;i<=3;i++){
                arrayOfBalls.push(new Ball(Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100));
            }


            var animate = function(){


                for(var j = arrayOfBalls.length-1; j>= 0; j--){
                arrayOfBalls[j].checkBorders();
                arrayOfBalls[j].checkMaxSpeed();
                arrayOfBalls[j].addForce(Math.random(),Math.random());
                arrayOfBalls[j].addForce(0,0.00098);

                arrayOfBalls[j].display();
                arrayOfBalls[j].move();
                }
                window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            };
            animate();
        }
      }
    },


}
```

Comment: Yes the problem appears to be the clearRect() call in the display() function for each ball. I would try moving this to the start of the animate() function before the For loop so the canvas is only cleared once each animation frame.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks a lot. I'd accept the answer but i don't see the check box. I'll try to figure it out and accept asap.

Comment: Great. I have added the solution as an answer (comments can't be accepted). Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment the problem is the clearRect() call in the display() function for each ball. Normally the canvas needs to only be cleared once each frame/loop of the animation so the clearRect can be placed at the top of the animation function as seen here...

```
var animate = function(){

    // Clear the canvas just once each animation frame here
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

    for(var j = arrayOfBalls.length-1; j>= 0; j--) {
        arrayOfBalls[j].checkBorders();
        arrayOfBalls[j].checkMaxSpeed();
        arrayOfBalls[j].addForce(Math.random(),Math.random());
        arrayOfBalls[j].addForce(0,0.00098);

        arrayOfBalls[j].display();
        arrayOfBalls[j].move();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```